# Aid needed with school task

Tags: python

I was given an assignment for my computer science class with the goal of creating a number guessing game. I have created the program but I cannot seem to solve some problems that I came across while making it.

The code I wrote is....

```
import random 

print("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game!")

Play_again = "yes"
i = 10
tries = 0

Random_Number = random.randint(1,100)

print("A random number between 1 and 100 has been generated.")
print("You have 10 tries to guess the number.")

while Play_again.casefold() == "y" or Play_again.casefold() == "yes": 
    Guess = int(input("Whats your guess?:"))
    i -= 1
    tries += 1
    if Guess == Random_Number:  
        print(f"Correct! You got in {tries} tries!")
        Play_again = input("Would you like to play again (N/Y)?")
        if Play_again.casefold() == "yes" or Play_again.casefold() == "y":
            continue
        elif Play_again.casefold() == "no" or Play_again.casefold() == "n":
            print("Thank you for playing!")
            break
    elif Guess > Random_Number:
        print(f"Your guess was too high. You have {i} guesses left." )
    elif Guess < Random_Number:
        print(f"Your guess was too low. You have {i} guesses left.")

    if i == 0: 
        print("Sorry you have no more guesses left.")
        Play_again = input("Would you like to play again (N/Y)?")
        if Play_again.casefold() == "yes" or Play_again.casefold() == "y":
            continue
        elif Play_again.casefold() == "no" or Play_again.casefold() == "n":
            print("Thank you for playing.")
            break
        else: 
            print("You have entered an invalid input.")
            break
```

Some of the problems I have with this code is that the randomly generated number stays the same even after you have played one game and are on your second. At first, I thought of putting the `random.randint(1,100)` inside the `while loop`, but that just creates a random number every time you guess. The second problem is that the 'i' and 'tries' values continue to go down but I need them to reset to their original value every time the user plays a new game.

By a new game I mean when the user answers 'yes' to `Play_again`.

Comment: Try making two loops: one for the main game that sits inside of a second loop that checks whether you are still playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick fix, create a 'reset' function, that updates all necessary variables:

```
import random 

print("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game!")

Play_again = "yes"

def reset():
    print("A random number between 1 and 100 has been generated.")
    print("You have 10 tries to guess the number.")
    i = 10
    tries = 0
    Random_Number = random.randint(1,100)
    return (i, tries, Random_Number)


i, tries, Random_Number = reset()
while Play_again.casefold() == "y" or Play_again.casefold() == "yes": 
    Guess = int(input("Whats your guess?:"))
    i -= 1
    tries += 1
    if Guess == Random_Number:  
        print(f"Correct! You got in {tries} tries!")
        Play_again = input("Would you like to play again (N/Y)?")
        if Play_again.casefold() == "yes" or Play_again.casefold() == "y":
            i, tries, Random_Number = reset()
            continue
        elif Play_again.casefold() == "no" or Play_again.casefold() == "n":
            print("Thank you for playing!")
            break
    elif Guess > Random_Number:
        print(f"Your guess was too high. You have {i} guesses left." )
    elif Guess < Random_Number:
        print(f"Your guess was too low. You have {i} guesses left.")

    if i == 0: 
        print("Sorry you have no more guesses left.")
        Play_again = input("Would you like to play again (N/Y)?")
        if Play_again.casefold() == "yes" or Play_again.casefold() == "y":
            i, tries, Random_Number = reset()
            continue
        elif Play_again.casefold() == "no" or Play_again.casefold() == "n":
            print("Thank you for playing.")
            break
        else: 
            print("You have entered an invalid input.")
            break
```

Output:

```
...
Your guess was too low. You have 0 guesses left.
Sorry you have no more guesses left.
Would you like to play again (N/Y)?y
A random number between 1 and 100 has been generated.
You have 10 tries to guess the number.
Whats your guess?:2
Your guess was too low. You have 9 guesses left.
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I made full code for you check this out:

```
import random
import sys

def menu():
    Play_again = input("Would you like to play again (N/Y)?").lower()
    if Play_again.casefold() == "yes" or Play_again.casefold() == "y":
        game()
    elif Play_again.casefold() == "no" or Play_again.casefold() == "n":
        print("Thank you for playing.")
        sys.exit()
    else: 
        print("You have entered an invalid input.")
        menu()

def game():
    i = 10
    tries = 0
    Random_Number = random.randint(1,100)
    #print(Random_Number)
    while i>0:
        try:
            Guess = int(input("Whats your guess?:"))
            i -= 1
            tries += 1
            if Guess == Random_Number:  
                print(f"Correct! You got in {tries} tries!")
                menu()    
            elif Guess > Random_Number:
                print(f"Your guess was too high. You have {i} guesses left." )
            elif Guess < Random_Number:
                print(f"Your guess was too low. You have {i} guesses left.")
        except:
            print('Please Enter Numbers only')


    print("Sorry you have no more guesses left.")
    menu()

if __name__=='__main__':
    print("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game!")
    print("A random number between 1 and 100 has been generated.")
    print("You have 10 tries to guess the number.")
    game()
```

In addition, I made it to get only numbers.
If there is an error in this code, tell me I'll fix it for you.